# How remove connection from login list in Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database-connection

In list of logins exists name, which I don't use. I want remove this name from list. How to do it?
[image: SANEK - it is login, which I want remove]

Comment: highlight those just click delete

Comment: @Jonathan where? I don't see deleting.  I want remove name from list.

Comment: when you are hovering the mouse on the list It will become blue color then click on delete button it will be removed

Comment: @Jonathan, it is clear space of login. I want remove login name from list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want remove connections from login list in Microsoft SQL Server 2014.
Go to folder:

> C:\Users\'WindowsUser'\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\12.0\SqlStudio.bin

**WindowsUser** - name of user in system Windows. Delete file **SqlStudio.bin**. Then your list of connections will be empty. How to delete a specific connection line - remove specific text from file **SqlStudio.bin**.